# more characters than the original

Tags: c

im trying to replace all no alfabetic char with blankspace but this increase the amount of characters by a lot, anyone that knows how to solve this problem?

input:(The Project Gutenberg EBook of A Tale of Two Cities, by Charles Dickens

This eBook is for the use o)

output: The Project Gutenberg EBook of A Tale of Two Cities  by Charles Dickens    This eBook is for the use

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

FILE * fp;

FILE * newFile;

fp = fopen("/Users/renatorollino/Desktop/labb.txt", "r");

newFile = fopen("/Users/renatorollino/Desktop/newlabb.txt", "w");

if(fp==NULL){

    printf("File could not open");
}

else{
    
    while (1) {
        char c = fgetc(fp);
        if(isalpha(c)){
            if (feof(fp)) break;
            fputc(c, newFile);
        }else{
             if (feof(fp)) break;
            c = ' ';
            fputc(c, newFile);
        }
            
    
   
    }fclose(fp);
}
printf("done");
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Can you please clarify what is the exact input, expected result and actual result?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the source file is not ASCII?

```
    while (1) {
        int c = fgetc(fp);      // changed type to int
        if (c == EOF) break;    // removed feof()

        if ((c < 0) || (c > 127)) continue; // ignore non-ASCII data

        if (!isalpha(c)) c = ' ';
        fputc(c, newFile);
    }
```

*Note: maybe better using *wide-char* functions.*

Answer (score 0):

wouldn't it be better to do an if statement like this:

```
(!isalpha(c)) 
{
   c = ' ';
}
```

Comment: it didnt change anything Gilad

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve.

If you want to replace all non letters with space, then you might want something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
  FILE* fp;
  FILE* newFile;

  fp = fopen("labb.txt", "r");
  if (fp == NULL) {
    printf("File could not open");
    exit(1);
  }

  newFile = fopen("newlabb.txt", "w");
  if (newFile == NULL) {
    printf("File could not open written");
    exit(1);
  }

  while (1) {
    char c = fgetc(fp);
    if (feof(fp))
      break;                  // end of file => exit the loop

    if (!isalpha(c))          // is it somethign else that A-Z or a-z?
    {
      c = ' ';                // replace with space
    }

    fputc(c, newFile);        // write character
  }
    
  fclose(fp);                 // close all files
  fclose(newFile);

  printf("done");
  return 0;
}
```

- The code is much simpler.
- There is error checking for `fopen` functions
- Added required all required `#include`s